# Python: Dynamically read and download an excel file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, amazon-s3

I'm able to dynamically read and return an csv file. But how to do the same with excel(with multiple sheets)

Read and return csv:

```
    obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key)
    df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()))
    filename = 'test.csv'
    resp = make_response(df.to_csv(index=False))
    resp.headers={ "Content-Disposition": "attachment;" "filename={}".format(filename) }
    resp.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/csv"
    return resp
```

Comment: It seems that this question is not related to flask; maybe best remove that tag and edit the title.

Answer (score 3):

When downloading a file, it doesn't matter what format it is.

And we're in luck with the Pandas team: they created `read_excel` for us: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

You'll have to determine which sheet you want to read into a frame, or concatenate them into another frame to your liking.

Comment: also note that the `io` for `read_excel` is allowed to be an s3 url.